# How to set or change swagger 404 response type

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-404, swagger

I generated an app using **swagger-node** (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node). I am using the **swagger validator** to find validation errors. It works fine, I am catching errors and changing them to the response format I prefer.

**I would like to handle also 404 error and return my own response.** Swagger returns automatic response when URL of a nonexisting page is provided and I would like to change it to my response.

Swagger response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /fhello</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I am looking for the way of changing it (to JSON).

Comment: console your error when you get 404 error put a condition

Comment: @ManjeetThakur I don't understand this approach. I don't have access to the error when it is thrown because it is managed somehow in the router for the swagger project before it gets to any of my controllers.

Comment: Paste you code here so i can understand about it

Comment: It is a code generated with swagger-express-mw. I am accessing path which is not specified in swagger.yaml. It gives me some default 'HTML/text' response and I am looking for a way to return JSON. (so far i resigned from automatic routing and then there is this possibility, but I am looking for a way to do in while using the swagger router)

Comment: `swagger-express-mw` is an express middleware wrapper around `swagger-node-runner`.  If you're actually using it as middleware, then surely you have your own code as well?

Comment: Actually, I don't have any code taking part in the route to 404 and the problem/difficulty I am encountering exists also on the newly generated project. 
I am doing simple steps to generate node swagger app and running it.
(https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node)
Now, I would like it to return JSON instead of HTML 404 response while sending a query to a not handled path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved it.

The response I am getting is not from the **swagger-node-runner** or similar but from **finalhandler** module used by express.

So I was not handling 404 error in my server.

To handle 404 in the project generated by swagger-node one just have to add a middleware at the end of the path of middlewares, managing all the queries which were not caught by the previous middlewares.

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      return res.status(404).json({description: 'Page not found'});
  })
```

(and what was probably my main mistake - I was using a middleware with four parameters app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {}